# Python subprocess display logs on terminal and save in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, subprocess

I am running a Python script using subprocess and willing to save output to a file as well as show live logs on terminal.
I have written below code and its saving logs in file but not showing live script execution logs on terminal.

```
TCID = sys.argv[1]

    if TCID == "5_2_5_3":
        output = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, './script.py'])
        with open('scriptout.log', 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(output)
```

Comment: why not using the python logging module?

Comment: Have you tried to `print(output)`?

Comment: @Jason : No experience of using logging...any clue how can i use it with my code ?

Comment: check this out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6567/redirecting-subprocesses-output-stdout-and-stderr-to-the-logging-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will fix your issue

```
import subprocess

outputfile = open('scriptout.log', 'a')
process = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "127.0.0.1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    if output == b'' and process.poll() is not None:
        break
    if output:
        out = output.decode()
        outputfile.write(out)
        print(out, end="")

outputfile.close()
```

also I tried

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(["ping", "127.0.0.1"])
with open('scriptout.log', 'wb') as outfile:
    print(output)
    outfile.write(output)
```

but it outputs after command execution ends. Also I want try with logging module but I don't know how to use it sorry :(